# MySQL Query: Select...Not In () in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a value of `$completedId="1,2,3,4,5";`

When I run this query in phpmyadmin, it gives the perfect output which is 6,7,8,9,10.

`select cmp_id from comprehension_master where cmp_id NOT in(1,2,3,4,5);`

But when I run the below given query in php, it shows output as `2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.`
Query only is being executed for value 1.

```
$completedId="1,2,3,4,5";
$query="select cmp_id from comprehension_master where cmp_id NOT in('".$completedId."')";
$result=$con->query($query);
$cnt=0;
while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
    $cmpId[$cnt]=$row[0];
    $cnt++;
}
$cnt=0;
print_r($cmpId);
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `single quote` from the query. It will treat it as string and truncate other ids.

Take a look at the below query and try with this.

```
 $query="select cmp_id from comprehension_master where cmp_id NOT in(".$completedId.
 ")";
 $result=$con->query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually when run as:

```
$query="select cmp_id from comprehension_master where cmp_id NOT in('".$completedId."')";
```

It treated as:

```
$query="select cmp_id from comprehension_master where cmp_id NOT in('1,2,3,4,5')";
```

**Issue:**

MYSQL consider it as a full string `('1,2,3,4,5')`

**What you need here?**

Just remove quotes, no need to use quotes around your IDs like this example:

```
$query="SELECT cmp_id FROM comprehension_master WHERE cmp_id NOT IN ($completedId)";
```

**If you echo your query it will looks like:**

```
SELECT cmp_id FROM comprehension_master WHERE cmp_id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```